# When do I need to call `super` from a constructor?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Reading [Dr. Axel Rauschmayer's blog on ES6 classes](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html), I understand that a derived class has the following default constructor when none is provided

```
constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
}
```

I also understand that if I want to use `this` within a constructor I first need to call `super`, otherwise `this` will not yet be initialized (throwing a ReferenceError).

```
constructor(width, height) {
    this.width = width;  // ReferenceError
    super(width, height);
    this.height = height; // no error thrown
    ...
}
```

Is the following assumption then correct?  (and if not, could you please explain the conditions under which I should explicitly call `super`)

For derived classes, I only need to explicitly call `super` when...

1. I need to access `this` from within the constructor
2. The superclass constructor requires different arguments then the derived class constructor

Are there other times when I should include a call to the superclass constructor?

Comment: No, there are not. What kind of "proof" do you want for that statement?

Comment: when you make a class like `class ABC extends DEF { ...` then you have to put `super(...args);`, because you just stated with `extends DEF` that you want to derive from it. If you don't derive from any class then just don't put 'super' in the ABC's constructor. It's that simple.

Comment: @Azamantes: There is no need to call `super` if the parent class takes the same arguments as the child class.

Comment: what if the derived class does define a constructor?  do i then need to include an explicit call to super? in other words, is the default call to super only included as part of the default constructor? (not sure of the use case here, just trying to think of edge cases)

Comment: @sfletche Yes, there is no "default `super` call" for all constructors, it's only part of the default constructor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that sounds correct, albeit a bit oddly formulated. The rules should be

- In a derived class, you *always*<sup>1</sup> need to call the `super(…)` constructor
- If you are not doing more than the default constructor, you can omit the whole `constructor(){}`,
  which in turn will make your class code not contain a super call.

<sub>1: You don't need to call it in the suspicious edge case of explicitly `return`ing an object, which you hardly ever would.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `super` in a subclass constructor in these cases:

- You want to reference `this` in the subclass constructor
- You don't return a different object in the subclass constructor

In other cases, you can call it if you want the superclass constructor to run, but you don't have to.

```js
class SuperClass{
  constructor() {
    console.log('SuperClass');
  }
}
class SubClass1 extends SuperClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log('SubClass1');
    super();
    return {};
  }
}
class SubClass2 extends SuperClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log('SubClass2');
    return {};
  }
}
new SubClass1();
new SubClass2();
```

I don't see how the order of arguments matters when deciding whether you should call `super` or not.

Comment: when i want to reference `this` anywhere in the subclass?  or just anywhere in the subclass constructor?

Comment: @sfletche yes, he means the constructor

Comment: @sfletche The other things in a class are just methods, I meant the constructor, yes.