# ExpressJS SubClasses Missing Inherited attributes and properties in Callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, express, inheritance

I am using ExpressJS 4.16 on Node v8.9.4, and have created base controller that handles default routes. Here is an sample example:

```
class BaseController {
  constructor(name, app, router, data) {
    this._name = name;
    this._app = app;
    this._router = router;
    this._data = data;

  }

   get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  setup_aggregate_routes() {
     //Add Top Level Routes (All Entities)
    this._router
       .route(this.aggregate_route) // route = {application_root}/{entity}s/
       .get(this.get_aggregate_request)
  }

  default_request(req, res) {
    res.status(400).json(this.not_implemented_message);
  }

  get aggregate_route() {
    return `/${this.name}s`;
  }
  get_aggregate_request(req, res) {
    this.default_request(req, res);
  }
}
```

The "this._router" is an "express.router()" object and the "this._app" is an express object.
I then proceed to inherit from this class as so.

```
const BaseController = require("./base");
class CatalogController extends BaseController {
  get_aggregate_request(req, res) {
    console.log(this._data);
    console.log(this.name);
    res.status(200).json();
  }
}
```

However, when doing this when I am in the get_aggregate_request callback for the subclass "CatalogController", "this" is undefined. I then proceed to replace "this" with "super" but the properties such as "_data" are not available and  "name" getter is called but when it uses this._name it is not available.

I am stumped as to why. Any assistance to properly wire this up would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Here is an example of how super is being used:

```
const BaseController = require("./base");
class CatalogController extends BaseController {
  get_aggregate_request(req, res) {
    console.log(super._data);
    console.log(super.name);
    res.status(200).json();
  }
}
```

Here is an example of how the class is instantiated:

```
const catalog_controller = new CatalogController(
  "catalog",
  app,
  express.Router(),
  data.catalog
);
```

** Additional information **
In order to address this problem I simplified the code and removed Express from the equation

Base Controller:

```
class BaseController {
  constructor(
    name, data
  ) {
    this._name = name;
    this._data = data;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }

  setup_aggregate_routes() {
    //Add Top Level Routes (All Entities)
    this.example_test_function(null, this._data, this.callback)
  }

  example_test_function(err, data, cb){
    cb(data);
  }

  callback(data){
    console.log(`${this.name}: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
  }

  default_request(req, res) {
    res.status(400).json(this.not_implemented_message);
  }

  get_aggregate_request(req, res) {
    this.default_request(req, res);
  }

}
module.exports = BaseController;
```

Catalog Controller (inherited):

```
const BaseController = require("./base");

class CatalogController extends BaseController {
  callback(data) {
    console.log(`${this.name}: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
  }
}

module.exports = CatalogController;
```

Driver:

```
const BaseController = require("./base")
const base_controller = new BaseController("base",
{ a:"abc" }
)

base_controller.setup_aggregate_routes()

const CatalogController = require("./catalog");

const catalog_controller = new CatalogController(
    "catalog",
   { a:"abc" }
  );

catalog_controller.setup_aggregate_routes()
```

Since ES2015/ES6 does not require an explicit call to the super constructor in a subclass constructor if the signatures are the same. The subclass ends up using the base (super) class constructor. So this is not an inheritance problem. I then tested the above and ran into a similar problem. It is not a problem with Inheritance or Express. It is the old javascript context problem and using "this".

This is identified here.
[How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Based on the last identified sample, if I change the code based on one of the identified solutions:

from:

```
cb(data);
```

to:

```
cb.bind(this)(data);
```

It works. 
I will provide a complete solution using ExpressJS as well

Comment: Show how you use `super`

Comment: how are you calling `get_aggregate_request`.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma - It occurs in this line of the code .get(this.get_aggregate_request). It is part of the Router Object. When a get operation occurs based on the route, the callback to this.get_aggregate_request is invoked

Comment: @thomann061 - the question has been updated

Comment: can you add route as well? you are using super incorrectly.

Comment: @RahulSharma, The route is in this line 
this._router
       .route(this.aggregate_route) which is `/${this.name}s`; based on what the getter aggregate_route includes.

Comment: why such a complex routing? you can make it simple.

Comment: @RahulSharma - I am not certain what you mean by complex. It is a base class and I have numerous classes that inherit the same base class. Keep in mind this is not the full example. This is just a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is associated to context, callbacks and the use of "this" and not an inheritance problem nor Express problem. 
It is identified here:

[How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

If I was using my original example to correct this problem, the only change I would need to apply is the following:

Change this:

```
.get(this.get_aggregate_request)
```

To this:

```
.get(this.get_aggregate_request.bind(this))
```

Of course there are other ways to resolve the context problem as identified in the article but that is ultimately up to you.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. It was confusing not seeing a super call.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class CatalogController extends BaseController {

    constructor(name, app, router, data) {
        super(name, app, router, data);
    }

    get_aggregate_request(req, res) {
        //super(req, res); // if you want to call
        res.status(200).json();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using the ES2015/ES6 standard. Typically the constructor is not needed if it has the same signature. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-useless-constructor. However, I will test this.

Comment: Typically the constructor is not needed if it has the same signature - ??? You **always** need to call super like above. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41350931/when-do-i-need-to-call-super-from-a-constructor)

Comment: @thomann061 - In ES2015/ES6,  you do not have to provide a constructor if the signature is the same. If it is not provided it just calls the super class constructor. The call chain is exactly the same and I have tested this on multiple scenarios.

The above example does not work. It fails at the same location. This problem is not an inheritance problem. I believe it is a problem with the combination of inheritance with Express 4 and the way it is handling the call back.

Comment: This really sounds like an inheritance problem. `this` is undefined because `super` is not called.  If you haven't passed `name`, `app`, `router`, `data` to the base class, then yes those values will be undefined. Unless you are not showing all of the code in `CatalogController`, I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is an Express issue. Everything works as expected, f I remove the express portions of the code. I will provide an example of this above.